# Java: Ошибка при прохождении тестов 'Unparseable number: "no"'

Tags: java, maven

Есть задачка :

> **"напишите программу для решения квадратных уравнений"**.
> *Условия ввода/вывода стандартны*.

мое решение:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);

    double a = scanner.nextDouble();
    double b = scanner.nextDouble();
    double c = scanner.nextDouble();

    double bRoot = -b;
    double discriminant = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    double rootPlus = (bRoot + (Math.sqrt(discriminant))) / (2 * a);
    double rootMinus = (bRoot - (Math.sqrt(discriminant))) / (2 * a);

    if (a > 0) {
        if (discriminant == 0) {
            System.out.println(rootPlus);
        } else if (discriminant > 0) {
            System.out.println(rootMinus + " " + rootPlus);
        } else if (discriminant < 0) {
            System.out.println("no roots");
        }
    } else if (a < 0) {
        System.out.println("no roots");
    }
}
```

}

Но при прогоне тестов выдает непонятную ошибку

```
Tests run: 14, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.317 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.epam.rd.autotasks.QuadraticEquationTest
test2Roots{String, String}[4]  Time elapsed: 0.019 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "no"
    at com.epam.rd.autotasks.QuadraticEquationTest.parseNumber(QuadraticEquationTest.java:145)
    at com.epam.rd.autotasks.QuadraticEquationTest.parseRoots(QuadraticEquationTest.java:111)
    at com.epam.rd.autotasks.QuadraticEquationTest.test2Roots(QuadraticEquationTest.java:59)
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "no"
    at com.epam.rd.autotasks.QuadraticEquationTest.parseNumber(QuadraticEquationTest.java:143)
    at com.epam.rd.autotasks.QuadraticEquationTest.parseRoots(QuadraticEquationTest.java:111)
    at com.epam.rd.autotasks.QuadraticEquationTest.test2Roots(QuadraticEquationTest.java:59)
```

При переходе на `QuadraticEquationTest.java:59` показывает:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("testCases2Roots")

void test2Roots(final String input, final String expected) {
    setControlledStreamsWithInput(input);
    try {
        QuadraticEquation.main(new String[]{});
        controlledOut.flush();

        double[] expectedRoots = parseRoots(expected);
        double[] actualRoots = parseRoots(getActualOutput());

        assertArrayEquals(expectedRoots, actualRoots, 0.00001, "Error on input " + input);
    } finally {
        setStandardStreams();
    }
}
```

Не могу сам разобраться, вроде все тесты пройдены, но ошибка есть.

Comment: У вас странная логика в решении квадратного уравнения, в частности для случая `a == 0` _вывод вообще отсутствует_., хотя решение есть `-c/b`.  При `a < 0` существуют решения

Comment: По условиям a гарантировано не равен 0

Comment: `-x^2 + x + 2 =0 --> x^2 - x - 2 = 0 --> x1 = 2, x2 = -1`

Comment: Воспользуйтесь отладчиком и проверьте, какие данные идут в падающий метод `parseRoots` в _обоих случаях_ его вызова.  По стектрейсу не понятно, на каком именно вызове происходит эта ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как это вы вычисляете корни `Math.sqrt(discriminant)`, презрев знак детерминанта?

Сначала необходимо проверить `if (discriminant >= 0)`, и только при положительном исходе считать `rootPlus` и `rootMinus`.

А вот от знака коэффициента `a`  наличие решений напрямую не зависит.

```
double discriminant = b * b - 4 * a * c;
if (discriminant > 0) {
   double rootPlus = (bRoot + (Math.sqrt(discriminant))) / (2 * a);
   double rootMinus = (bRoot - (Math.sqrt(discriminant))) / (2 * a);
   System.out.println(rootMinus + " " + rootPlus);
 } else if (discriminant == 0) {
        System.out.println(-b/ (2 * a));
 } else {
        System.out.println("no roots");
 }
```

Comment: напишите программу для решения квадратных уравнений.
Для заданных коэффициентов квадратного уравнения (ax² + bx + c = 0), верните один или два корня уравнения, если они существуют в области действительных чисел.

Входное значение задается через System.in. Выходное значение должно быть напечатано в System.out.

Формат вывода:

"x₁ x₂" (два корня в любом порядке, разделенные пробелом), если есть два корня
"x" (просто значение корня), если есть единственный корень
"no roots" (просто строковое значение "без корней"), если корня нет.
Параметр a гарантированно не равен нулю.

Comment: Отлично, это стандартная постановка задачи. В школе на математике же вы решали квадратные уравнения, при a<0 ветви параболы просто направлены вниз, что не мешает им  пересечь ось абсцисс, если другие параметры позволяют

Comment: Изменил первоначальную проверку с "a" на  "discriminant" - результат не изменился. Ошибка та же.

Comment: Я привел логику решения (не тестировал). Результаты с ним должны быть верными. Если ваше решение неверное, то оно может дать "no roots" в случае, когда система тестирования ожидает числа

Comment: Ваш код работает без ошибок. Но в чем разница мне не понятно пока. Только разбираюсь в ЯП. И самое непонятное мне это условие о гарантии  "a !=0", которое у Вас не прописано в решении. В общем понял что алгоритм вычисления корня можно прописывать только после проверки дискриминанта, но почему? И спасибо Вам за решение!

Comment: `о гарантии "a !=0"`  это как раз гарантировано условием, тестирующая система не подаст на вход нулевое значение, и в данном случае  проверять не нужно. Если же ввод осуществляется человеком, то, конечно, на ноль проверить надо, чтобы на него не делить. Т.е. полное решение кв. уравнения сначала включает проверку a==0, и если да, то и проверку b==0.